How to type a dynamic component in a generic vue component?
I have a "calendar" component. This component will consume some data from the caller, and display all the days in a month - if there exists some data for that day, then I want to then display another component. The issue is that my calendar component doesn't know what type of component it should end up displaying in each of the day slot.
I expected that I could just use a Vue3 generic component and say:

The data could be passed through as a prop of type Record<string, T[]> (where the key is just Y-m-d)
The component I want it to use would be passed through as a prop of type DefineComponent<T>

// Calendar.vue
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
import {computed, DefineComponent, ref} from "vue";
import CalendarDay from "./CalendarDay.vue";

type Props<T> = {
    data: Record<string, T[]>,
    component: DefineComponent<T>,
    labelFn: (length: number, date: Date) => string,
};
const props = withDefaults(
    defineProps<Props<T>>(),
    {
        labelFn: (count, date) => `${count} items on ${date.toLocaleDateString()}`
    }
);

const currDate = new Date();

const currentValue = ref<{year: number, month: number}>(
    {
        year: currDate.getFullYear(),
        month: currDate.getMonth() + 1
    }
);

const dayArray = computed<number[]>(() => {
    const date = new Date();

    const {year, month} = currentValue.value;

    const numbers: number[] = [];

    date.setFullYear(year, month-1, 1);
    while (date.getMonth() == month - 1) {
        numbers.push(date.getDate());

        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return numbers;
})

</script>

<template>

    <div aria-live="polite" class="calendar-table">
        <p v-for="i in 7" :key="i" class="calendar-table-header" aria-hidden="true">
            <span class="long-name">
                {{(new Date(2022, 7, i)).toLocaleString(undefined, {weekday: "long"})}}
            </span>
            <span class="short-name">
                {{(new Date(2022, 7, i)).toLocaleString(undefined, {weekday: "short"})}}
            </span>
        </p>

        <CalendarDay
            v-for="day in dayArray"
            :label-fn="props.labelFn"
            :data="props.data"
            :component="props.component"
            :date="new Date(Date.UTC(currentValue.year, currentValue.month - 1, day))"
        />
    </div>
</template>

// CalendarDay.vue
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
import { computed, DefineComponent} from "vue";

type Props<T> = {
    data: Record<string, T[]>,
    component: DefineComponent<T>,
    labelFn: (length: number, date: Date) => string,
    date: Date
};
const props = defineProps<Props<T>>();

const dateStr = computed(() => `${props.date.toISOString().split('T')[0]}`);

const value = computed((): T[] => props.data[dateStr.value] ?? []);
const style = computed(() => props.date.getDate() == 1 ? {"grid-column-start": props.date.getDay()} : null)
</script>

<template>
    <div class="day" :class="{'has-items': value.length > 0}" :style="style" :aria-hidden="value.length == 0">
        <div class="day-content" :aria-label="labelFn(value.length, props.date)">
            <p class="date" aria-hidden="true">
                {{ props.date.getDate() }}
            </p>
            <template v-for="val in value">
                <component :is="component" v-bind="val"/>
            </template>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

Although this works in the browser, the typescript compiler complains:
Type 'DefineComponent<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, {}, string, PublicProps, Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{}>>, {}, {}>' is not assignable to type 'DefineComponent<{}>'.ts(2322)
Calendar.vue(7, 5): The expected type comes from property 'component' which is declared here on type '{ data: Record<string, {}[]>; component: DefineComponent<{}>; labelFn: (length: number, date: Date) => string; } & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & Record<...>'

Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '(CreateComponentPublicInstance<Readonly<T extends ComponentPropsOptions<Data> ? ExtractPropTypes<T> : T>, {}, {}, ComputedOptions, ... 15 more ..., {} & EnsureNonVoid<...>> extends { ...; } ? Props : any) & Record<...>'.  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<Readonly<T extends ComponentPropsOptions<Data> ? ExtractPropTypes<T> : T>, {}, {}, ComputedOptions, ... 15 more ..., {} & EnsureNonVoid<...>> extends { ...; } ? Props : any'.ts(2345)
CalendarDay.vue(1, 34): This type parameter might need an `extends CreateComponentPublicInstance<Readonly<T extends ComponentPropsOptions<Data> ? ExtractPropTypes<T> : T>, {}, {}, ComputedOptions, ... 15 more ..., {} & EnsureNonVoid<...>> extends { ...; } ? Props : any` constraint.
CalendarDay.vue(1, 34): This type parameter might need an `extends (CreateComponentPublicInstance<Readonly<T extends ComponentPropsOptions<Data> ? ExtractPropTypes<T> : T>, {}, {}, ComputedOptions, ... 15 more ..., {} & EnsureNonVoid<...>> extends { ...; } ? Props : any) & Record<...>` constraint.

A vue playground of a consumer of the component is here (in this vue playground)
What's the correct way to type this so the compiler can make sure that the data matches the props for that component?

Can you confirm the problem exists on build? Because it could be specific to editor where you see the error.

Yes, I get the same thing locally. The messages are slightly different but it's the same lines that error.

How exactly? With vue-tsc? Please, add the relevant code parts to the question, it needs to be understandable if external link is unavailable

I suppose you can just use Component type instead of DefineComponent. Even if what you tried were supported, I doubt that you could benefit from a detailed type that a generic provides. TS support in templates is still new, but you can open an issue

Playground
The Component type works fine:
Calendar.vue
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends Record<string, any>">
import {type Component, computed, ref} from "vue";
import CalendarDay from "./CalendarDay.vue";

type Props<T> = {
    data: Record<string, T[]>,
    component: Component<T>,
    labelFn: (length: number, date: Date) => string,
};

...

So you can use it without any types:
<script setup lang="ts">
import Calendar from './Calendar.vue';
import SessionLink from "./SessionLink.vue";

//type Props = {days: Record<string, Array<InstanceType<typeof SessionLink>['$props']>>};

const props /*: Props */ = {
  days: {
    "2024-08-31": [
        {
          some: 'some',
          data: 'data'
        }
    ]
  }
}

function label(count: number, date: Date) {
    return `${count} sessions on ${date.toLocaleDateString()}`;
}
</script>

<template>
  <Calendar :data="props.days" :component="SessionLink" :label-fn="label" />
</template>

If you provide wrong types :component will be errored, if you want more fine control, use
type Props = {days: Record<string, Array<InstanceType<typeof SessionLink>['$props']>>};

so wrong types would be errored in the data.
